# NodeJS websocket server on Plesk doesn't answer

Tags: javascript, node.js, plesk

I am new to NodeJS and I have just set up a subdomain to work with it on my Plesk Onyx 17.5.3 server.
I have done a simple websockets chat app but it doesn't work.

If I start the app via command line doing:

```
node server/server.js
```

the app works flawlessly. The code in server.js is:

```
"use strict";

process.title = 'node-chat';

const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
const PORT = 9000;
const wss = new WebSocketServer({port: PORT});

console.log('WSS');

let messages = [];
wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
  console.log('WS connection');
  messages.forEach(function(message){
    ws.send(message);
  });
  ws.on('message', function (message) {
    messages.push(message);
    console.log('Message Received: %s', message);
    wss.clients.forEach(function (conn) {
      conn.send(message);
    });
  });
});

wss.on('error', function(obj){
  console.log('WS error');
  console.log(obj);
});

console.log((new Date()) + 'server.js started');
```

If I start the application using Plesks "Restart app" it doesn't work. Doing a ps aux I can see the process is working. In the log file I see it has started:

```
App 17579 stdout: WSS
App 17579 stdout: Fri Jul 28 2017 13:52:44 GMT+0200 (CEST)server.js started
```

But there is no log saying websocket server has started or crashed, it just doesn't work. If I try to connect a client side js app to the server gives an error saying it can't connect to the server:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://server_address:9000/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Any clues?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

May I ask where you found the Nodejs logs on Plesk? And how are you able to get to the console on plesk?

As an answer to your question:

It could be that the port you provided is not configured to allow traffic from the web to your node application. That's why I'd recommend using

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 9000;
```

This line will try to use the port that could be configured in an object containing the user environment data.